# URL Dynamically changes after first edit

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, web-crawlers, google-index, soft-404

We are developing a magento eCommerce website with main category pages, sub-category pages and details page along with other static pages.

Our condition is if any miss-spelled URLs entered directly in browser then it will be redirected to the index page.

Whenever we upload new product. the URL of this product is automatically generated with unique ID number generated in url.

**say like this :**: www.example.com/cityname/categoryname/subcategory/123/product.

where ID number is 123.

After if some changes need to be done on particular product. Then we edit this product accordingly.

Here the problem is the product unique ID is automatically disappeared after second edit, thus resulting this page redirected to the index page.

As a result huge number of soft 404's are appearing our Webmaster account.

Kindly help to resolve this issue.

Comment: "unique ID is automatically disappeared" - just from links to this page? Is the old URL (with unique ID) still valid? "Our condition(ht.access) is miss-spelled URLs to be redirected to the index page." - Why "ht.access"? I assume this should be `.htaccess`? How do you determine that a URL is "misspelled" (in .htaccess)?

Comment: i mean , if any miss-spelled url entered directly on browser, then it will be redirected to the home page.